# Max Distance of a Simple Random Walk on Integers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, algorithms, random-walk, applications

I encounter this when proving bounds for a randomized algorithm, which is mathematically formulated below. Many thanks for any thoughts or discussions given.

Consider simple random walk $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$, where each iid $X_i = \pm 1$ w.p. 1/2 each.

The goal is to find the smallest possible function $f(n)$:
For every positive $n$, w.p. $1-\frac 1 n$ that $\forall i = 1, \cdots, n$ we have $|S_i| = O(f(n))$

With @stochasticboy321 suggestion, I apply Hoeffding inequality and find $O(\sqrt{n\log n})$ would make an upper bound with probability at least $1 - 1/n$. I wonder if this is the smallest possible function.

Comment: I know the law of iterated logarithms but not I am sure if it is helpful here, as we are also worried about non-limiting cases. I tried to consider $\max |S_i|$, and $S_n^2$; both got me not far. I am not even sure what concentration inequality to apply here. Any thoughts will be helpful!

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. How can you have $S_1 = O(f(n))$ and $S_n = O(f(n))$? What is the meaning of an equality sign between a random variable and big-O notation?

Comment: @snar Well, it might be a CS-way of using big-O. What I am trying to do here is to bound the max distance of this random walk. In an algorithmic sense, this random walk algorithm do not go too far in all iterations before iteration $n$ with probability $1 - \frac1n$. Here, big-O really means to have an upper bound. This upper bound is indeed trivial for small $i$, but gets significant quickly if we get a tight bound $O(f(n))$. If we bound the probability of each "event" wrt $i$ separately, we shall be using some union bound over all events to bound the probability.

Comment: Are you saying you want one function for both bounds, or are you OK with having one function serve as an upper bound and a different function serve as a lower bound? (NB: The second is doable, but I think the first may be impossible.)

Comment: @AaronMontgomery One function. By lower bound, I mean I also want to show that f(T) cannot be smaller wrt constant factor.

Comment: I *think* you won't be able to get one function to do both simultaneously. You'll need something close to $\sqrt n$ to capture the top-end behavior, but I think the frequency of returns of $S_n$ to $0$ would imply you'd need $0$ for the lower bound (subject to the $1 - 1/n$ probability condition you specified). This is of course not a proof, and I very well could be wrong somewhere.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Sorry, my previous expression caused some confusion. I did not mean to find a lower bound on $f(n)$. What I mean is to prove that $f(n)$ is the smallest possible function up to a constant factor.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Also, $\sqrt{n}$ the max distance in expectation. For a concentration-type inequality we need here, it is not sufficient. In addition, the Law of Iterated Logarithm suggests that $\sqrt{n\log \log n}$ is needed. However, that is a limiting behavior and I am not sure how this comes in here.

Comment: But surely the LIL gives you the lower bound, right? It says that w.p. $1$,$\lim\inf |S_n|/\sqrt{n\log\log n} = c $ for some constant $c$. So, no function smaller than $\sqrt{n\log\log n}$ will do.
For upper bounds, there is certainly work on non-asymptotic laws of iterated logarithm. For example, this has a particularly clean version - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.08240.pdf (equation (8)).
As an aside, for finite horizons as you have, you should at least be able to show $O(\sqrt{n\log(n)})$ bounds in an elementary way, have you done that?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Indeed LIL gives the lower bound. I suspect that in the finite cases, the limiting behavior does not necessarily apply, right? For $O(\sqrt{n\log n})$, I once had this idea, but I do not know how to prove that. Any hints for it?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 In fact, only the finite cases need to be considered, because, in an algorithmic sense, we always terminate at some finite point.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks for that bound. It turns out to be super easy. But I am still stuck whether if it is the smallest possible function to upper bound it for finite cases.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Hi, I just want to give you an update of my solution. $O(\sqrt{n\log n})$ is tight. We can consider the limiting case where $n$ goes to infinity and the  $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ converges to normal distribution. Lower bound the integration from $\ln n$ to infinity by density function at $\ln n$, we get the desired result. Thanks for the hint of $\sqrt{n\log n}$!

Comment: I think that the lower bound you have is an artifact of the fact that you demand probability $1- 1/n$. If you loosen this to $1 - o(1),$ (as this stuff is usually studied) then the LIL type results should be tighter.  (Look at the eq (8) I mentioned above, you'll see an additive $\log(1/\alpha)$ term that is winning out here). Anyway, cool that you figured it out, happy to have helped. I'll try to find a convincing non-asymptotic proof for the LIL lower bound in the case we relax to $1 - o(1)$ as above.

Comment: Also, in the updated Q., you only mention the Hoeffding inequality. Did you also apply the union bound at some point? That is a key ingredient in this strategy for what you're trying to show, and if you didn't the proof might be wrong...

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks again. Indeed the 1/n was the key of this bound. I guess the LIL stuff is beyond my scope rn. Lastly, I did use union bound :)

Comment: A small commment about using the CLT - note that the CLT itself is asymptotic. For non-asymptotic versions of the CLT (i.e., the Berry-Esseen bounds), there's a catch that they only give probability estimates up to a $1/\sqrt{n}$ error. This means that you cannot directly solve for $1/n$ in the Gaussian tail - you don't have non-asymptotic guarantees that the same is a $1-1/n$ quantile for your distribution - the error could make it only a $(1-\Theta(1/\sqrt{n}))$-quantile.

Comment: That said, you can show that the $2/\sqrt{n}$-tail is a $1/\sqrt{n}$-tail for you, and since $1/\sqrt{n} >1/n$ while their logarithms have the same order of growth, the lower bound doesn't really change - just that the rigorous argument via CLT is a little more complicated. You can also directly work with the setting you have, since it is simple enough, but the CLT argument has a simplicity of form that is nicer.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I guess the asymptotic behavior is what confuses me in the first place. I was trying to draw connections between the asymptotic and finite behaviors but did not find a great argument to convince myself. I guess the non-asymptotic versions will give me more insight there. Thanks very much for making these inspiring comments.